# Insert row in SQLite with Ormlite containing ENUM_INTEGER and DATE_TIME data type

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

This is my entity class. I use three ENUM_INTEGER data type in this class

```
@DatabaseTable
public class MessageData {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
    private Integer messageId;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_TIME, columnName = DATE_FIELD_NAME)
    private Date date;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_INTEGER, columnName = DIRECTION_FIELD_NAME)
    private MessageEnums.MessageDirection direction;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = CONTACT_ID_FIELD_NAME)
    private String contactId;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = MESSAGE_FIELD_NAME)
    private String message;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_INTEGER, columnName = TYPE_FIELD_NAME)
    private MessageEnums.MessageType type;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = CONTENT_ADDRESS_FIELD_NAME)
    private String contentAddress;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_INTEGER, columnName = STATUS_FIELD_NAME)
    private MessageEnums.MessageStatus status;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = READ_FIELD_NAME)
    private boolean read;

    //.....
}
```

and this is my enumeration class

```
public class MessageEnums {
    public enum MessageDirection{
        IN,
        OUT
    }

    public enum MessageType{
        TEXT,
        VOICE,
        IMAGE,
        STICKER,
        AUDIO,
        VIDEO,
        LOCATION
    }

    public enum MessageStatus{
        PENDING,
        SENT,
        DELIVERED,
        RECEIVED
    }
}
```

I use this code to insert a row

```
newMessageData = new MessageData(date, MessageEnums.MessageDirection.OUT, params[2], params[1]
                    , MessageEnums.MessageType.TEXT, "", MessageEnums.MessageStatus.SENT, true);

        Dao<MessageData, Integer> dao = myApplication.getMessageDatabaseHelper().getMessageDao();
        dao.create(newMessageData);
```

I get this error after running last line

Unable to run insert stmt on object com.x.xx.database.MessageData@41a72790: INSERT INTO `messagedata` (`date` ,`direction` ,`contactID` ,`message` ,`type` ,`contentAddress` ,`status` ,`read` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

hope somebody help me!

Comment: THe exception should have more information.  What does the caused by message say?

Comment: Dear @Gray Maybe the message can help. cause = java.sql.SQLException: Could not use reflection to get millis from Joda DateTime: Mon Jan 12 13:18:18 GMT+03:30 1970

Comment: I use this code to fill date variable :         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = c.getTime();

Comment: I'm sure that this cause with date field because when I send null for date the row inserted successfully.

Comment: sorry for continuous comments. I changed the data type of date field FROM DATE_TIME to DATE_STRING and now everything is OK. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from date field. when I changed data type from DATE_TIME to DATE_STRING problem solved. I don't know what is the problem of DATE_TIME.

Comment: DATE_TIME is used for Joda DateTime. You are using the java.util.Date.